# Heroku console command error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque

I'm reluctant to ask this but I can't figure it out. When I run the following command in `heroku console` I get a syntax error. Why?

```
QUEUE='*' rake jobs:work
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: compile error
/home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
QUEUE='*' rake jobs:work
          ^
/home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150
/home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150:in `call'
/home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:28:in `call'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
```

My resque.rake file includes the alias `task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"` and the command was copied verbatim from the console's history so I know it's been run before.

Comment: did you try with `QUEUE="*"` ?

Comment: Yes. Same error comes up. Restarted the app as well.

Comment: Does it work in development mode, or is this only on heroku?

Comment: Hi Neil. Only on Heroku. It works just fine in development on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using anything but the Cedar stack then you're limited to using DelayedJob on Heroku.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queueing#background_jobs_on_herokubamboo

Comment: I feared this. Will have to upgrade Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

The Heroku console is a Rails console, it's not a bash shell.

You're trying to execute `QUEUE='*' rake jobs:work` as if it were a valid Ruby command, which of course it isn't.

Are you perhaps trying [to do this?](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/6/20/the_new_heroku_1_process_model_procfile/) (scroll down to "run anything" where it talks about Resque).

Comment: Thing is, I'm on the bamboo stack which doesn't support Procfile.

Comment: You could change stacks: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack#migrating_to_a_new_stack